# How to include dynamic JSP from another server on a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, jspinclude

I am writing a some code that to dynamically include an HTML snippet in a page.  Basically, I have course information on one server, which I want other servers to be able to include with a single line of code.

If it was on the same server, I would use this:

```
<jsp:include page="coursedescription.jsp?subj=ENGL100" />
```

But the JSP page is on a different server.  This is what I have tried, and it does not work:

```
<jsp:include page="http://myotherserver.com/courselist.jsp?subj=ENGL" />
```

How can I include that snippet from the other JSP page, by specifying the URL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use `c:import` tag for doing this. The other way is to fetch the content in the server side using commons HTTP and include the result inline.

Comment: Thanks, this works great: 

<c:import url="http://myotherdomain.com/courselist.jsp?subj=ENGL" ></c:import>